# How to know written var type with Clang using C API instead of actual?

Tags: c++, c, clang

I'm trying to use Clang via C API, indexing to be detailed. The problem is that some types are returned not as they are written, but as they are for compiler. For example "Stream &" becomes "int &" and "byte" becomes "int.

Some test lib:

```
// TODO make it a subclass of a generic Serial/Stream base class
class FirmataClass
{
public:
    FirmataClass(Stream &s);

    void setFirmwareNameAndVersion(const char *name, byte major, byte minor);
```

I'm using the code to get method information:

```
void showMethodInfo(const CXIdxDeclInfo *info) {
    int numArgs = clang_Cursor_getNumArguments(info->cursor);
    fprintf(stderr, "  %i args:\n", numArgs);

    for (int i=0; i<numArgs; i++) {
        CXCursor argCursor = clang_Cursor_getArgument(info->cursor, i);
        CXString name = clang_getCursorDisplayName(argCursor);
        CXString spelling = clang_getCursorSpelling(argCursor);

        CXType type = clang_getCursorType(argCursor);
        CXString typeSpelling = clang_getTypeSpelling(type);

        CXCursorKind kind = clang_getCursorKind(argCursor);

        fprintf(stderr, "  kind=[%s (%i)], type=[%s], spelling=[%s]\n",
            cursor_kinds[kind], kind, clang_getCString(typeSpelling),
            clang_getCString(spelling));

        clang_disposeString(name);
        clang_disposeString(spelling);
        clang_disposeString(typeSpelling);
    }

    // return type
    CXType returnType = clang_getCursorResultType(info->cursor);
    CXString returnTypeSpelling = clang_getTypeSpelling(returnType);

    fprintf(stderr, " returns %s\n", clang_getCString(returnTypeSpelling));
    clang_disposeString(returnTypeSpelling);
}
```

Output:

> [105:10 4689] access=[CX_CXXPublic]
>   kind=[CXIdxEntity_CXXInstanceMethod] (21)
>   name=[setFirmwareNameAndVersion] is_container=[0]    3 args:
>   kind=[CXCursor_ParmDecl (10)], type=[const char *], spelling=[name]
>   kind=[CXCursor_ParmDecl (10)], type=[int], spelling=[major]
>   kind=[CXCursor_ParmDecl (10)], type=[int], spelling=[minor]
>   returns void

So you can see that `byte` function arguments are described as `int`.
How can i get actual spelling?

Answer (score 2):

Is `byte` declared via a typedef, or a #define?

When I declare these types:

```
typedef int MyType_t;
#define MyType2_t int

class Foo
{
public:
    bool bar( MyType_t a, MyType2_t b );
};
```

And then print the type names I get from `clang_GetTypeSpelling` this is what I get:

```
bool Foo_bar(  MyType_t a, int b )
```

Libclang presumably can't print the #defined name because the preprocessor has already replaced it with `int` by the time the parse tree is built.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved this a few days ago.

```
"Stream &" becomes "int &" and "byte" becomes "int.
```

libclang doesn't know what `Stream` or `byte` are until you insert the standard headers manualy using the flag `-isystem <pathToStdHeaderDirectory>`

I wrote a C# function that retrieves all the visual studio VC headers include directory:

```
    private static string[] GetStdIncludes()
    {

        using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio"))
        {
            if (key != null)
            {
                var lastVcVersions = key.GetSubKeyNames()
                    .Select(s =>
                    {
                        float result = 0;
                        if (float.TryParse(s, System.Globalization.NumberStyles.Float, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out result))
                            return result;
                        else return 0F;

                    }).Where(w => w > 0F)
                    .OrderByDescending(or => or)
                    .Select(s => s.ToString("n1", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
                    .ToArray();

                foreach (var v in lastVcVersions)
                {
                    using (var vk = key.OpenSubKey(v))
                    {
                        var val = (string)vk.GetValue("Source Directories");

                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(val))
                            return val.Split(";");
                    }
                }


            }
        }
        throw new Exception("Couldn't find VC runtime include directories");
    }
```

hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue with my own classes.

You need to pass on the same flags you would use for compiling with clang to either clang_parseTranslationUnit or clang_createTranslationUnit, in particular the -I flags which are used to look up the header files where your class or type definitions are.
it seems that if libclang can't find a type declaration, it just defaults to all of then to int.

calling clang_createIndex ( 1, 1 ) should provide you with hints on what you are missing via stderr.

Here is some sample code that works for me now:

```
int main ( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
    char *clang_args[] =
    {
        "-I.",
        "-I./include",
        "-I../include",
        "-x",
        "c++",
        "-Xclang",
        "-ast-dump",
        "-fsyntax-only",
        "-std=c++1y"
    };
    CXIndex Idx = clang_createIndex ( 1, 1 );
    CXTranslationUnit TU = clang_parseTranslationUnit ( Idx, argv[1], clang_args, 9, NULL, 0, CXTranslationUnit_Incomplete | CXTranslationUnit_SkipFunctionBodies );
    clang_visitChildren ( clang_getTranslationUnitCursor ( TU ),
                          TranslationUnitVisitor, NULL );
    clang_disposeTranslationUnit ( TU );
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to get the AST for a header file, hence the CXTranslationUnit_Incomplete | CXTranslationUnit_SkipFunctionBodies flags and -ast-dump -fsyntax-only command line options, you may want to omit them if you dont need them and of course add and change the -I parameters according to your needs.